# How to import a GraphML to JGraphT

Tags: jgrapht, graphml

JGraphT has a GraphMLExporter that enables to export a graph to a GraphML file.
There doesn't seem to be a GraphMLImporter.

Is there a simple way to generate a graph in JGraphT from a .grphml file?

Comment: I didn't find any GraphMLImporter and the GraphMLExporter did not provide the expected information about the generic objects held by jgrapht. Therefore I used JAXB to import and export my graph to XML file.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from version 1.0.0 JGraphT has both an importer and an exporter for GraphML. The classes are named `GraphMLImporter` and `GraphMLExporter` inside the jgrapht-ext package.

Starting from version 1.1 all importers and exporters are located in the jgrapht-io package. Additionally, a simpler version called `SimpleGraphMLImporter` which provides less functionality in favor of greater speed is also available in latest versions.

A demo is also available, see [GraphMLDemo](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-demo/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/demo/GraphMLDemo.java).

Comment: I am not asking anything. This is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jgrapht-sna](https://bitbucket.org/sorend/jgrapht-sna/) project. Beside implementations of SNA algorithms, it has `GraphMLImporter` class.